# NodeJS how to seek a large gzipped file?

Tags: node.js, gzip

I have a large GZIP-ed file. I want to read a few bytes from a specific offset of uncompressed data.

For example, I have a file that original size is 10GB. In gzipped state it has size 1GB. I want to read a few bytes at 5GB offset in that 1GB gzipped file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to read all of the first 5 GB in order to get just those bytes.

If you are frequently accessing just a few bytes from the same large gzip file, then it can be indexed for more rapid random access. You would read the entire file once to build the index. See [zran.h](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/develop/examples/zran.h) and [zran.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/develop/examples/zran.c).